# Bind click to select options but not to the select element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, html-select

Is there a way to bind a click event to the select options and not to the select box itself?

The change event also won't work for me because when I first click the box I'm not able to select the first option (since it's already selected by default), and I really need to be able to also select the first option.

Is there any way to get around this, either binding a click or a change event?

Comment: Add a 'Please select...' option or run the change code on page load?

Comment: one other wrench to throw in here...a user could TAB to the select box and make a selection without ever using the "click" event.

Comment: have you tried `$('option').click(function(){//..some code here});`?

Comment: @Town Though of putting a disabled option in there, looks kinda unnecessary since i already have that on a label, but yes that does work. Dont really know about that page load idea, could u post an simple example ? @kasdega it has to be a click but thanks for the idea. @Trey yes i did try that and it does not work, don't know why though.

Comment: @mfreitas: I've posted an answer with those two in it.  I think you've missed the point of @kasdega's comment - the user _could_ tab to the `select` box which wouldn't fire the `click` event, so if you rely solely on the `click` you could end up with erroneous results.

Comment: @town exactly!  I'm trying to point out that the controls on the page can be manipulated by using the keyboard and not the mouse (so no "click" event).  As a for instance in the fiddle posted by town select a value and then hit up and down arrow a few times.  The value changes but no click event will be fired.

Comment: @kasdega & @mfreitas: Hence using the `change` event instead - `change` fires when the `select` loses focus, whereas `click` would not.

Comment: @Town you're right i didnt read it properly. Ultimately there will be key control over it. I'm more worried about mouse clicks for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either:

**a)** Add a '*Please select...*' `option` as the default item in the `select`.

**b)** Run the '*selection changed*' code on page load to pick up the default, [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/b5eN8/).

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>

Current Value: <span></span>
```

and

```
// call the changed function on document ready
// to get the 'default' value
$(function() {
    selectionChanged();
});

// hook up the change event of the select box
$('select').change(selectionChanged);

// event handler for the change event
function selectionChanged(e) {
    $('span').html($('select').val());
}
```